# Endroid/Qrcode library with wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api

Hello friends i have an issue with endroid/qrcode libarary i created custom page template and the function .getContentType(); return the link of the page, and insert it into the img src, instead return the path of the actual image path that was created, i will glad for some helps, and advice's, thanks appreciate it so much :-)
 This is my code, out side of wordpress it works perfectly but when i put it in a custom page template or cpt template the function above return the wrong path..

```
<?php
include WP_CONTENT_DIR .'/endroid_qrcode/src/QrCode.php';

use Endroid\QrCode\QrCode;


$qr = new QrCode();

$qr
->setText('http://www.solutions.com')
->setSize(200)
->setLabel('Scan the code', 16, __DIR__.'/../font/open_sans.ttf')
->setPadding(10)
->setErrorCorrection('high')
->setForegroundColor(['r' => 0, 'g' => 0, 'b' => 0, 'a' => 0])
->setBackgroundColor(['r' => 240, 'g' => 230, 'b' => 255, 'a' => 0])
->setLabel('Scan Me For Info')
->setLabelFontSize(16)
->setPadding(10)
->setImageType(QrCode::IMAGE_TYPE_PNG);
//->setLogoSize(98)
//->setLogo('logo/logo_tetrom.PNG')



$qr->render();

// save it to a file
$qr->save('wp-content/endroid_qrcode/generated_qr/qrcode_new.png');

// now we can directly output the qrcode


header('Content-Type: '.$qr->getContentType());
?>
```

[output in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXijd.png)

as u can see in the screenshot the function inserted the link to the page instead the file path,

```
($qr->save('wp-content/endroid_qrcode/generated_qr/qrcode_new.png');)
```

the file was created, but the src in the img tag is generated the wrong way, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know that library directly, but from the code you posted it looks like the `a` component likely represents opacity. Since you sei it to zero I expect you are getting a completely transparent image.

Try setting `a` to 255 (in both places) or removing it completely.

Comment: I tired your solution but it's no working,it's nothing to do with the background color or layover, as u can see in the screen shot i attached, there is an error msg, plus in the inspector the src for the img is not correct, the function used the url for the current page, instead inserted the image real path that was created..
The code is working well outside of wordpress. i created a pure php file from scratch,and the image is appeared with the qr code and everything was working well...it's something with wordpress page template that getContentType() function returns the wrong URL...